# How do I select a value from a dropdown element?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a different type of HTML dropdown it seems so I can't select a value from it, using Selenium Webdriver. How do I make a dropdown a SelectElement so i can use SelectElement.SelectByValue?

I have tried the following but get an error

`IWebElement qualification = driver.FindElement(By.Id("qual"));
SelectElement qSelect = new SelectElement(qualification)`

This is the HTML

```
<div>
   <inv-drop-down-select [width]="268" identifier="qualification" id="qual" formControlName="Qualification" [items]="qualifications">
   </inv-drop-down-select>
</div>
```

and I tried to do this

```
IWebElement qualification = driver.FindElement(By.Id("qual"));
SelectElement qSelect = new SelectElement(qualification)
```

I get the following error

OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException: 'Element should have been select but was inv-drop-down-select'

HTML is

```
<span _ngcontent-wiv-c81="">Please Select...</span> <li _ngcontent-wiv-c81="" role="menuitem" class="ng-star-inserted"><a _ngcontent-wiv-c81="" class="selected"><span _ngcontent-wiv-c81="">Masters</span></a></li> <li _ngcontent-wiv-c81="" role="menuitem" class="ng-star-inserted"><a _ngcontent-wiv-c81=""><span _ngcontent-wiv-c81="">Degree</span></a></li>
```

Comment: You have to handle the target value as another WebElement (locate and click).

Comment: select will not work as drop down is made of div and spans. Could you share HTML code for drop down , at least for 3 elements.

Comment: <span _ngcontent-wiv-c81="">Please Select...</span>
<li _ngcontent-wiv-c81="" role="menuitem" class="ng-star-inserted"><a _ngcontent-wiv-c81="" class="selected"><span _ngcontent-wiv-c81="">Masters</span></a></li>
<li _ngcontent-wiv-c81="" role="menuitem" class="ng-star-inserted"><a _ngcontent-wiv-c81=""><span _ngcontent-wiv-c81="">Degree</span></a></li>

Comment: Please edit your question and put that HTML in it with code formatting ...